# Example of a package that has the same name in two different distros but refers to unrelated upstream projects for each?

Tags: packaging, distributions

I'm thinking about organization of open source packages across different distributions, and one of the issues that might arise is that different distributions decide to assign a different package name to the same thing, or to have a package with the same name that refers to one thing in one distro and something completely different in another.

Are there any practical examples of the latter, or is it just a theoretical possibility? I've searched for a while and did not find an actual example that I could point at and say "here, this scenario has actually happened".

Comment: If `rename` has its own package that would be a candidate. Can't test this right now so not offering a full answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`docker`

Ubuntu 15.04:

```
$ lsb_release -rd
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04

$ apt-cache show docker
Package: docker
...
Description-en: System tray for KDE3/GNOME2 docklet applications
 Docker is a docking application (WindowMaker dock app) which acts as a system
 tray for any desktop environment, allowing you to have a system tray    without
 running the KDE/GNOME panel Docker was designed to work with Openbox 2, but it
 should work fine in any window manager.
Description-md5: 032a37ba6228c22cbca1c0b960030eaa
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

Fedora 22:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME=Fedora
VERSION="22 (Twenty Two)"

$ dnf info docker
...
Available Packages
Name        : docker
...
Description : Docker is an open-source engine that automates the deployment of any
        : application as a lightweight, portable, self-sufficient container that will
        : run virtually anywhere.
        :
        : Docker containers can encapsulate any payload, and will run consistently on
        : and between virtually any server. The same container that a developer builds
        : and tests on a laptop will run at scale, in production*, on VMs, bare-metal
        : servers, OpenStack clusters, public instances, or combinations of the above.
```

Comment: Hah, thought the same thing, having been caught out installing the "wrong one"