# package versioning across distributions

Tags: debian, ubuntu, package-management, rpm, distributions

Goal is to identify a package version across distros RPM based Fedora, CentOS, RedHat etc. Can I rely on upstream version to be same on all the distros? If yes then how can I retrieve (RPM or DEB) upstream version number from command line?

---

Can't post this as an aswer -->

These dependencies that are listed in rpm -qp -requires .rpm are virtual packages if automatic dependencies is specified in .spec file. These virtual packages are NOT library soname but rather just virtual package names (even though they look like soname).

e.g. on Fedora 27, this works

```
$ rpm -q --whatprovides "libQt5Core.so.5()(64bit)"        
qt5-qtbase-5.9.2-5.fc27.x86_64
```

but this doesn't

```
$ rpm -q --whatprovides libQt5Core.so.5
no package provides libQt5Core.so.5
$ rpm -q --whatprovides libQt5Core
no package provides libQt5Core
$ rpm -q --whatprovides Qt5Core
no package provides Qt5Core
```

If your own .rpm itself bundles the libraries (i.e. provides these virtual packages) then RPM will not complain if these virtual packages are not installed on the system since they are supplied with your package.

Comment: No, and no[.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429654/package-versioning-across-distributions)

Comment: [Here is a good example of why you can't](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223378/example-of-a-package-that-has-the-same-name-in-two-different-distros-but-refers), but I'm sure we've got the opposite question around somewhere (if only 
I can find it).

Comment: @MichaelHomer+ the most commonly annoying example is RedHat httpd = Debian apache2 .

Comment: Reading between the lines it sounds like their might be some other actual goal? Like seeing which is the most recent package across distros, or something else?

Comment: @pbhj You are right. I want to generate RPM package with manual dependencies and but dont know what version and name to use because this RPM package should be usable across CentOS, Fedora, RedHat and couple of other RPM based distros.

Comment: @PnotNP.  You should avoid specifying exact version numbers.  Instead spcify a minimum vesions number for each package your package is dependent on.

Comment: Even package **names** differ between various RPM-based distributions.  Try contrasting Red Hat, SuSE, Magea :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot depend on (all) Linux distributions using the same upstream version of a particular package at any one time as each distribution has its own development cycle.

While you will see a lot of commonality in package names across distributions, there is no guarantee.  As a rule of thumb, package names will be mostly the same across a distribution and any derived downstream distributions. Think Debian and Ubuntu for example, or Redhat and CentOS.

Comment: This.  The apache2 webserver package in Debian can be gotten with `apt-get install apache2` whereas in RedHat et al it would be `yum install httpd`.  Been so long since I used slackware I'm not sure what that package name would be....

Comment: Since i'm creating one Deb and one RPM package, is it safe to assume that name specified in DEB will be same across all debian based distros? And the same assumption for RPM  based distros? It seems from your response that answer would be no.

Comment: @PnotNP.  Somewhat safe for the major distributions if no dependencies but no guarantees. If you have dependencies, you will probably have to do a package per major distribution.